# Ruby routing duplicate routes for filtering can be done better

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to catch all the combinations of the following since a user can choose to filter using location, dates, price, rating, reviews, name

At the moment my main routes to catch is the following:

```
get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/ratings/:rating/reviews/:reviews/name/:name' => 'controller1#index'
```

How do I make it catch all the options for it ?

Does this route catch if you put in the url the address:

```
www.example.com/ratings/5  ?
```

In order to catch all the possibilities I will have to write:

```
    get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/ratings/:rating/reviews/:reviews' => 'controller1#index'
    get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/ratings/:rating' => 'controller1#index'
    get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices' => 'controller1#index'
    get ':location/dates/:dates' => 'controller1#index'
    get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/reviews/:reviews/name/:name' => 'controller1#index'
    get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/ratings/:rating/name/:name' => 'controller1#index'
    get ':location/dates/:dates/prices/:prices/ratings/:rating' => 'controller1#index'
```

And many many more in order to catch them all

Comment: Please, provide an example that this route doesn't catch

Comment: @Phil Done, I've added an example which route it doesn't catch and it doesn't catch all the other combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that routing is not what you need. In your situation you have 2 nice options:

1. To pass your filters as parameters in url after "?" (easy way)
2. To Use taxonomy paradigm (hard way)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [bound parameters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters) section of docs. Try to write something like:

```
get ':location(/:dates(/:prices(/:rating(/:reviews(/:name')))))'
```

Comment: It works but I can't differ between the parameters. Sometimes the user will use the prices and reviews filters only for example, how do I know which parameter belongs to what?

Comment: Please be aware that on the client side I'm using backbone and the browser history in order not to refresh the page that's why I've used /rating/:rating, /prices/:prices....

Comment: Okay, I understood you.